# Query Firebase data on multiple reference IDs

Tags: firebase

I have data somewhat structured like below in Firebase. There is users having a list of groups they have access to. I wonder how I make a Firebase query only fetching the groups with $refIds equal to the once within the "groups" section in users. This is a many-to-may relationship. I would simply like to make a list of the groups the user is a member of.

Is the only option to fetch them one by one or is there a better solution?

```
users: {
    "$uid": {
        name: "John Doe",
        groups: {
            "$refId": true,
            "$refId": true
        }
    },
    "$uid": {
        name: "Jane Doe",
        groups: {
            "$refId": true
        }
    }
},
groups: {
    "$refId": {
        title: "Group 1"
    },
    "$refId": {
        title: "Group 2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, loading in the groups from the user node and iterating over that would get each group.

Another option is a slightly different group structure

```
groups: {
    "$refId": {
        title: "Group 1"
        uid0: true
        uid1: true
    },
    "$refId": {
        title: "Group 2"
        uid1: true
        uid3: true
    }
}
```

You could then query the groups node for uid1: true, which would only return the groups uid1 is part of; group 1 and group 2 in this case.

Comment: Great answer Jay! Quick note: the advantage of your second approach is that it allows direct access to the list of members. I would prefer to split out "group metadata" (i.e. title) from "group members". In addition you could consider storing some useful information about each member (e.g. their name) instead if `true`. That way you can show the list of group members with a single direct lookup, instead of multiple nested queries.